# nest : how use UpdateByQuery()?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I would like to use the UpdateByQuery() methode

If i understood well i need to give a query and a select.

for example i would like to change the name property to "welcome" in my proj class

I start to write my methode but i don't know what to do after that?

```
 client.UpdateByQuery<proj>(q => q.Query(rq => rq.Term(f => f.idProjet, projetEntity.IdProjet)));
```

I don't see Update fluent methode in the intellisense helper

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Script` method. This example should work:

```
var scriptParams = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"newName", "welcome"}};

client.UpdateByQuery<proj>(q => q
    .Query(rq => rq.Term(f => f.idProjet, projetEntity.IdProjet))
    .Script(script => script
        .Inline("ctx._source.name = newName;")
        .Params(scriptParams)));
```

To run this example you have to set [script.inline: true](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-security.html) in `elasticsearch.yml`. To avoid this you have to use `File()` method instead of `Inline()`.

Comment: Thank you for answere. Must I use a script as a string? Is there a way to use an intellisens?

Comment: Not that I know. Scripts are very powerful and using different languages. I cannot imagine how to handle foreach loops for example. And furthermore: using inline scripts is not the preferred way because of security issues. Files are the supposed way to use it.