# ElasticSearch C#/Next : Partial Update multiple documents

Tags: c#, updates, nest, elasticsearch-5

I want update many document match query with new value. I see it's possible to use Update by query like [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42214770/5625764) but I need update lot of subfields and is not "readable" in script.

I prefer if it's possible to work with PartialDocument. I image something like :

```
var docUpdate = new {
    user= new UserInfo { Id = "xyz", Name = "My User Name"},
    date= DateTime.UtcNow()
};

elsClient.Update<MyDocument, object>(
    q => q.Query(rq => rq.Term(f => f.idProjet, projetEntity.IdProjet)),
    descriptor => descriptor.Doc(docUpdate));
```

It's possible to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use an ExpandoOject as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796286/how-do-i-update-an-existing-document-inside-elasticsearch-index-using-nest)

Comment: No update method update only 1 document where I need update all document matchs with filter.Expect if update method is modified in last version of driver.

Comment: Then you need to write  update by query